# How to format the "datetime.timedelta" type

Tags: python

I'm calculating the difference between two time values like this:

```
current_time = '2019-08-22T17:58:28'
alert_time = '2019-08-22T16:58:28'

diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time, datetimeFormat) - datetime.datetime.strptime(alert_time, datetimeFormat)

diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)

print(diff)
1:00:00
```

So this works as expected, but i need to add the `diff` variable into a dictionary, and i only need to add the numerical difference, e.g. `3600`

So how can i format `diff` to just be `3600` ?

I know i can do `str(diff)` which returns `1:00:00` but i'd like the value to be in seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
import datetime

current_time = '2019-08-22T17:58:28'
alert_time = '2019-08-22T16:58:28'
datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time, datetimeFormat) - datetime.datetime.strptime(
    alert_time, datetimeFormat
)

d = diff.total_seconds()

print(d)
```

The output:

```
3600.0
```

---

## Update

After seeing @felixkagota 's answer. I did a quick google to figure out the difference between `timedelta.seconds` and `timedelta.to_seconds()`. Basically `timedelta.seconds` returns whole numbers, i.e: it doesn't account for fractions of a second. For example:

```
import datetime

current_time = '2019-08-22T17:58:28:000000'
alert_time = '2019-08-22T16:58:28:123456'
datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f'

diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time, datetimeFormat) - datetime.datetime.strptime(
    alert_time, datetimeFormat
)

print(diff.total_seconds())
print(diff.seconds)
```

gives:

```
3599.876544
3599
```

Answer (score 1):

just do diff.seconds. Timedelta class contains a seconds property that returns the timedelta value in seconds.